# Ansible playbook using private git role dependency

Tags: git, ansible

I have an issue running an Ansible playbook with a set of private roles (that is, Ansible roles in a private git repository).

For example, I have a playbook that uses the role `base` which depends on `dep`, both of which are hosted in private git repositories. Running `ansible-galaxy` fetches and installs all roles and dependencies as it should, but later `ansible-playbook` fails at using the correct role name.

`play.yml`

```
- hosts: test
  roles:
    - role: base
```

`requirements.yml`

```
- name: base
  src: ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-base.git
  scm: git
```

`role-base/meta/main.yml`

```
galaxy-info:
  author: Me
  description: Test Ansible role dependencies
  min_ansible_version: 1.9
  platforms: Ubuntu
dependencies:
  - name: dep
    src: ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-dep.git
    scm: git
```

---

```
$ ansible-galaxy -r requirements.yml
- executing: git clone ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-base.git base
- executing: git archive --prefix=base/ --output=/tmp/tmp4YKG7a.tar
- extracting base to ansible-roles/base
- base was installed successfully
- adding dependency: dep
- executing: git clone ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-dep.git dep
- executing: git archive --prefix=dep/ --output=/tmp/tmpT2YiW4.tar
- extracting base to ansible-roles/dep
- dep was installed successfully

$ ansible-playbook play.yml
ERROR: expected a role name in dictionary: {'scm': 'git', 'src': 'ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-dep.git', 'name': 'dep'}
```

I tried using the alternative role-name system as the dependency:

```
dependencies:
  - role: "git+ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-dep.git,,dep"
```

Which is fine for `ansible-galaxy` but still `ansible-playbook` fails...

```
$ ansible-galaxy -r requirements.yml
- executing: git clone ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-base.git base
- executing: git archive --prefix=base/ --output=/tmp/tmpTcvpDu.tar
- extracting base to ansible-roles/base
- base was installed successfully
- adding dependency: dep
- executing: git clone ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-dep.git dep
- executing: git archive --prefix=dep/ --output=/tmp/tmpd726OV.tar
- extracting base to ansible-roles/dep
- dep was installed successfully

$ ansible-playbook play.yml
ERROR: cannot find role in <pwd>/roles/git+ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-dep.git,,dep or <pwd>/git+ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-dep.git,,dep or <pwd>/ansible-roles/git+ssh://git@10.0.0.1/ansible/role-dep.git,,dep
```

Is there a way to use role dependencies from private repos correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in the 1.9. I created a PR (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/13802) but I doubt it'll get merged as Ansible 2.0 has just been released.

Comment: 1.9.5 has been released now. Though I can't see your fix in the release notes: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-announce/h6KTqCd2r1c

Answer (score 0):

In `role-base/meta/main.yml` you define your role name as `dep`. Therefore you invoke it like:

```
- hosts: test
  roles:
    - role: dep
```

Comment: I'm not applying the role `dep` to any hosts, it should be pulled in as a dependency of `base`, as you see in the `play.yml` sample.